# Can function arguments be freely interchanged without affecting program behaviour?

Tags: programming-languages, theory, formal-languages

This is a question applicable a statically typed language that has functions (no optional parameters).

If I have some function that accepts, say, 5 parameters of types a, b, c, d, e in the following form:

```
function(a, b, c, d, e) {
    does things
}

// call syntax:
function(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Is it (theoretically) equivalent if I modify the function to accept the parameters in different order, given that I call it in that order?

```
function(e, a, d, b, c) {
    does things
}

// call syntax:
function(e, a, d, b, c);
```

Is there actual academic work on this matter or should the answer be trivial? (I'm not experienced with formal programming languages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, in the language, arguments can be function calls, and those functions can have side-effects, then putting those arguments in a different order will probably result in different behavior. (The language definition might say that the behavior is undefined in such a situation.)

Answer (score 0):

Strange question... anyway: from a formal point of view yes, the two declarations are equivalent, because you simply changed the name of the parameters:

> function(a, b, c) { ...

is the same as

> function(b, a, c) { ...

The previous formal name "a" now is b, and the name "b" changed into a.

Formal parameters are "formal"...

But probably you can't change the declaration without also changing the body, i.e.:

> function divide(a,b) { return a / b }

is not the same as:

> function divide(b,a) { return a / b }

In your example you changed *both* the declaration *and* the call... and this works as long as the type of the swapped parameters is the same, but it would not always work when types differ because things you can do on a type could be forbidden or behave differently on another type.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand your language semantics to allow for default arguments or partial function application, then order can very well start to make a difference. These problems can be fixed by providing keyword arguments, barring that, argument order becomes significant.

**Default Arguments**

Lets say you have the function definition-

```
function(a, b, c, d=1, e=2) {
    does things
}
```

Now, if you want to leave `d` as its default value but pass an argument for `e`, you'll need to either support passing `e` as a keyword argument, or reorder the parameters so that `e` comes before `d` in the parameter list.

Additionally, if we wanted to provide a default value for `b`, we'd have to move it to after `c` in the parameter list, otherwise the only way to call the function with `b` as its default is to provide `c` via a keyword.

**Partial Function Application**

Lets say you want to partially apply `a` and `b` to your `function`. We can do that, and get a function back that we can apply the rest of the arguments to.

```
g = function(a, b)
g(c, d, e)
```

However, if we wanted to partially apply only `d` and `e` instead, once again we cannot do that without keyword arguments.